# Cholesky decomposition on a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

Let $S = S^T$ be a symmetric $n × n$ matrix with Cholesky decomposition $S = LDL^T$ . Prove or disprove the following statements:

The diagonal elements of D are the eigenvalues of S.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: I informally proved that the product of the diagonals is the same as the product of the eigen values of S, also (not too sure about this) I showed that the trace of S is the same as trace (LDL^t), now i'm not sure if I have satisfied the conditions to just say it is a proof of the question!

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Take 
$$
S=\pmatrix{4&2\\2&1}
$$
with eigenvalues $0$ and $5$. The $LDL^T$ decomposition is given by
$$
S=\pmatrix{ 1& 0 \\ 1/2& 1} \pmatrix{ 4 & 0 \\0&0} \pmatrix{ 1& 1/2 \\ 0& 1}.
$$